# Servlet Exception during Unit Tests in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my project. When I do unit test for Spring Controller using MockMvc and Mockito, I get following error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
```

It happens due to the `this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(custCont).build();`line. I'm using maven for my dependencies, here they are:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
             <groupId>javax</groupId>
             <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
             <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you need any more info on the matter, I'd be more than happy to provide. Please, help me figure out what's causing the error.

Comment: check out http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/. Same issue you are facing.

Comment: @AniketThakur Unless I'm adding javaee.jar the wrong way (I've done it by adding to java build path - libraries in Eclipse) it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you remove `javaee-api` entry from maven dependency file?

Comment: @AniketThakur I didn't, now I did, the error stays

Comment: Try with add javax servlet dependency.

Comment: @Darshan As in `<dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId><artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId><version>2.5</version></dependency>`?

Comment: @KrzysztofPiszko yeah...

Comment: @Darshan Then it doesn't fix it...

Comment: @KrzysztofPiszko can you share stacktrace and application-context.xml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82820/discussion-between-krzysztof-piszko-and-darshan).